# Append URL with value specified in DIV

Tags: url, append

I know the first part of a URL, but need to define the last part uniquely based on what the client enters in a div. For example:

```
<!-- specify page name in the div -->
<div id="client-entry">page-name</div>
<div id="load-url">url loads here</div>

<!-- load what is specified at the end of the url -->
<script>
$("#load-url").load("known-folder/"#client-entry.text()".html");
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea 1:**

Give an attribute to div of your choice (Say for example **ajaxify**)

```
<div id="client-entry" ajaxify="unique link here">
```

then using jQuery you can get the value as

```
$('#client-entry').attr('ajaxify');
```

and then load the next div with whatever attribute value the client-entry div has has.

**Idea 2:**

You may use an input in the client-entry div as

then using jQuery get the value of input as

var toLoad = $('client-input').val( );

Use this value in your load code.

```
$("#load-url").load("known-folder/"+toLoad+".html");
```

Comment: You second idea was exactly what i was looking for. The only thing i changed was .val to .text and that worked perfectly. Thank you!